# Конфиг docker-compose в зависимости от переменных окружения

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Есть приложение в docker, в нём есть контейнер nginx, который его и отдаёт.

Приложение не знает об окружении в котором будет использоваться. Возможно, ему нужно пробросить свой порт на хост, чтобы им можно было пользоваться. Или же им будут пользоваться из другого контейнера и можно обойтись без задействования хост-порта.

Хочется в `docker-compose.yml` иметь возможность:

- Указывать порт в `.env`. Здесь всё просто: `ports: ${EXTERNAL_PORT}:80`
- Либо не указать вообще - тогда порт и не должен прокидываться. Список `ports` должен быть пустым.

Можно ли как-то это реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `docker-compose.yml` нет поддержки условий, поэтому вариант с `docker-compose.override.yml`, который вы сами
предложили - практически единственный способ добавления гибкости.

Другой вариант - использовать несколько yml-файлов. При запуске docker-compose можно указать несколько yml-файлов,
они будут слиты в единую конфигурацию: `docker-compose -f файл1.yml -f файл2.yml ... up ...`

### Кастомная конфигурация через Makefile

Нужно написать Makefile, который будет создавать кастомную конфигурацию. Таким способом можно реализовать любую логику.

Выглядит это следующим образом:

- есть файл конфигурации `.env`, который влияет на конфигурацию
- вы делаете `make up`, и утилита make запускает цель `up` из файла `Makefile`, в котором собирается собственный
  кастомный вариант `docker-compose-dev.yml`

Ниже - пример, в котором проверяется `.env` файл на наличие `HOST_PORT` и опционально добавляется порт.

Сначала устанавливаем утилиту `yq`, которая может сливать yaml-файлы:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rmescandon/yq
sudo apt-get install yq
```

`Makefile`:

```
####################################
# Список сервисов для запуска
####################################

SERVICES=www mysql nginx

# Запуск всех контейнеров
.PHONY: up
up: docker-compose-dev.yml

# для запуска с кастомной конфигурацией нужно раскомментировать следующую строку, она должна начинаться с Tab
# @docker-compose -f docker-compose-dev.yml up -d ${SERVICES}

# для примера тут запускается diff, который покажет разницу между 2 файлами
    @diff docker-compose.yml docker-compose-dev.yml || true

# файл-цель зависит от других файлов и будет пересобираться при их изменении
docker-compose-dev.yml: docker-compose.yml with-port.yml .env
    @/usr/bin/bash build-yml.sh
```

`build-yml.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

grep -qP '^HOST_PORT=' .env

[ $? -eq 0 ] && \
    yq merge docker-compose.yml with-port.yml > docker-compose-dev.yml || \
    cp docker-compose.yml docker-compose-dev.yml
```

`with-port.yml`:

```
services:
  www:
    ports:
      - "${HOST_PORT}:80"
```

`.env`:

```
# Порт приложения
HOST_PORT=8080
```

Проверка: запускаем `make up`, `diff` выдает такую разницу:

```
>     ports:
>       - "${HOST_PORT}:80"
```

Если удалить `HOST_PORT`, порт из yml-файла исчезает.

Я использовал связку `bash` + `yq`, но в более сложных кейсах лучше написать скрипт на более функциональном языке.

На enSO есть [аналогичный вопрос](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/338781).

Comment: Спасибо, интересный вариант. Но я добавил на эту тему обновление в мой ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Единственное, что придумал, это использовать [docker-compose.override.yml](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/).

- В основном docker-compose.yml не указываем вообще порт
- docker-compose.override.yml добавляем в игнор в репе
- В том окружении, где нужно создаём его и прописываем что-то вроде:

```yml
version: "3.8"

services:

    www:
        ports:
            - "${HOST_PORT}:80"
```

**UPDATE**

Второе решение - генерировать docker-composer.yml. У меня была идея сделать для этого простой шаблонизатор на PHP (так как проект на нём), в комментариях предлагают Makefile.

Проблема в том, что, раз мы используем Docker, то хотелось бы максимально разгрузить хост. Здесь же нам на хосте нужны языки/библиотеки для генерации конфига.

Так что второе решение (на любителя) - создать ещё один docker-compose-проект, предназначенный для генерации конфига для основного проекта :)

Comment: Я переосмыслил, вот что думаю. Как будут использовать контейнеры, вы не знаете. Вы хотите сейчас решить вопрос с портом. А ведь особенностей может быть довольно много, дело не ограничивается одним портом. Кто-то захочет добавить еще и контейнер, который будет собирать метрику, допустим. Или размещать в облаке (в этом случае докер-композ файл вообще не нужен). Я думаю, каждый доработает этот файл для своих потребностей.